# PHP - Forcing to NOT IGNORE same values in preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I've got a problem with `preg_match_all` function, which by default automatically ignore same values.

Code:

```
$data = '<img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">  <img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">  <img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">';
preg_match_all('#<img src="images/smiles/(.+?)" alt=".+" border="0">#',$data,$out);
print_r($out);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">  <img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">  <img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lol.gif
        )

)
```

I want `$out` variable to be something like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">
            [1] => <img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">
            [2] => <img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lol.gif
            [1] => lol.gif
            [2] => lol.gif
        )

)
```

Which flag or parameter should I add or change to have the above output?
Thanks in advance!

## EDIT

Of course I don't have only these HTML tags in `$data` variable, there are some other and text as well.

Comment: Did it occur to you to put the blame on your regex, not preg_match_all? Your match pattern is too greedy / not context-constrained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = '<img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">  <img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">  <img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">';
preg_match_all('#<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*[\'"]images/smiles/([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>#i', $data, $out);
var_dump($out);
```

Output is:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '<img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">' (length=59)
      1 => string '<img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">' (length=59)
      2 => string '<img src="images/smiles/lol.gif" alt="Laughing" border="0">' (length=59)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'lol.gif' (length=7)
      1 => string 'lol.gif' (length=7)
      2 => string 'lol.gif' (length=7)
```